# Setting an int to Nullable<long> using refection fails

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

```
public class Test
{
    public long? LongValue { get; set; }
}

//----------

var propInfo = typeof(Test).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance).FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == "LongValue");
//propInfo of Test.LongValue property

if (propInfo != null)
{
    int intValue = 99;
    var testObj = new Test();

    testObj.LongValue = intValue;         //This line succeeds 
    propInfo.SetValue(testObj, intValue); //This throws System.ArgumentException
}
```

propInfo.SetValue is throwing the following exception where as direct assignment succeeds.

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Object of type 'System.Int32' cannot be
>   converted to type 'System.Nullable`1[System.Int64]'.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Well, duh. You're going around all the syntax sugar the compiler usually does for you - the generated IL code does have explicit casts. You have to set the exact correct type, e.g. `new long?(intValue)`.

Comment: http://www.industryweek.com/site-files/industryweek.com/files/imagecache/large_img/uploads/2013/07/square-peg.jpg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the correct behavior.

The difference between a direct assignment and a reflection-based call of the setter is that in a direct assignment compiler knows the type of the property being assigned, and inserts the appropriate conversion for you. In other words, when you write this

```
testObj.LongValue = intValue;
```

the compiler interprets it in the same way as if you wrote

```
testObj.LongValue = (long)intValue;
```

because it knows that `LongValue` is of type `long`.

Reflection, on the other hand, is a rather low-level API, so it does not insert gratuitous conversions for you<sup>*</sup>, so you would need to add a cast to your code.

<sup>*</sup> Since all parameters of value types go through boxing and unboxing during a call through reflection, conversions that happen to be of a boxing type will succeed. For example, it is valid to pass `long` in place of a `Nullable<long>` parameter, because the value goes through a boxing conversion.

Comment: `rather low-level API` - isn't it, specifically, an unboxing issue?

Comment: @Rawling All value types go through unboxing, but that's an orthogonal issue: the real issue is that reflection would not apply type conversions at all, be it built-in or user-defined ones. It expects you to pass objects of a correct type, allowing for boxing only because there's no other way around passing parameters in an array of type `object[]`.

Comment: So... it disallows type conversions other than via boxing, but in this specific case it fails because the unboxing fails? It'll happily "type convert" a `long` to a `long?` *because that's a valid unboxing*.

Comment: @Rawling My point is that this is a side effect of having to go through boxing/unboxing in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to convert it to the type prior to setting the value.

```
long? temp = intValue;
propInfo.SetValue(testObj, temp);
```